# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un formContrlName de un formGroupName en un FormArray?

Tags: html, angular, ts

Estoy tratando de acceder a este formContrlolname = "idOpcion" que a su está dentro de un formGroup = "formGroup"

```
<ng-container formArrayName="encuestaCuantitativa"
                            *ngFor="let pregunta of preguntasData; let i = index">
                            <tr [formGroupName]="i">
                                <td class="text-primary">{{pregunta.pregunta}}</td>
                                <td formGroupName="opcion" style="min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px">
                                    <ng-select sm class="form-control-sm" formControlName="idOpcion"
                                        (change)="onChangeDetalle(pregunta, i, $event)" placeholder="-"
                                        [clearable]="false">
                                        <ng-option *ngFor="let opcion of pregunta.opciones"
                                            [value]="opcion.idOpcion">
                                            {{opcion.valor}}. {{opcion.opcion}}
                                        </ng-option>
                                    </ng-select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
```

Tengo hasta ahora solo esto

```
validarSupervisionDesembolso() {
const a = this.formGroup.get('encuestaCuantitativa') as FormArray;
console.log(a)
```

}
Que me bota este resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas acceder paso por paso a cada uno de los elementos, tendrías que hacer algo así

```
const indexDeLaPregunta = 0; //Posición de la pregunta en el array [0-n]

const encuesta = this.formGroup.get('encuestaCuantitativa') as FormArray;
const pregunta = encuesta.at(indexDeLaPregunta); //FormGroup
const opcion = pregunta.get('opcion'); // FormGroup
const idOpcion = opcion.get('idOpcion'); //FormControl
```

Y si solo necesitas el ìdOpcion de una pregunta especifica, puedes acceder directamente así:

```
const indexDeLaPregunta = 0; //Posición de la pregunta en el array [0-n]
const idOpcion = this.formGroup.get(
  `encuestaCuantitativa.${indexDeLaPregunta}.opcion.idOpcion`
);
```

un saludo

Comment: Hey hola que tal :D, muchisimas gracias me ayudó mucho, sabes como podría decirle que no sea requerido ? es que tengo varios formularios y si le quito de manera global le quito a todos. Intenté con .setValidators([]) pero no me funciona :(

Comment: Así sin ver el código y el ambos contextos me es difícil ayudarte. Crea por favor otra pregunta explicando en detalle el problema que tienes. un saludo